# NullPointerException in retrieving data

Tags: java, hibernate, session, transactions

I am trying to retrieve data by using hibernate with fixed data. But the data can be retrieved before commit transaction. After transaction is commit, I can only get `null` object. Here is my Main.java code:

```
package com.SSH.Action;

import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import com.SSH.Model.Address;
import com.SSH.Model.Contact;
import com.SSH.Model.Phone;

public class Main {
    private static SessionFactory factory; 
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
    try{
         factory = new     Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
      }catch (Throwable ex) { 
         System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
         throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex); 
      }

    Set<Phone> phoneSet = new HashSet<Phone>();
    Phone phone= new Phone();
    phone.setAreaCode(80);
    phone.setNumber(123456);
    phoneSet.add(phone);
    Address address = new Address();
    address.setCity("City");
    address.setStreet("Street");
    address.setHomeNo("12");
    Contact contact = new Contact();
    contact.setAddress(address);
    contact.setPhone(phoneSet);

    Main me = new Main();

    me.saveContact(contact);
    me.getContact();

    }

public void saveContact(Contact contact){

    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(contact);
        System.out.println(session.get(Contact.class, new Long("1")).getAddress().getCity()); // result 'City'
        tx.commit();
    }catch(HibernateException he){
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        he.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close();
    }
 }

 public void getContact(){
    Session session = factory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = null;
    try{
        tx = session.beginTransaction();
        System.out.println(session.get(Contact.class, new Long("1"))); // result 'null'
        tx.commit();
    }catch(HibernateException he){
        if (tx!=null) tx.rollback();
        he.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        session.close(); 
    }
   }
  }
```

I can get `Contact` object before transaction is commit. How should I get that object from `getContact` method. 
When I use this code :

```
session.get(Contact.class, new Long("1")).list();
```

This Hibernate exception is thrown:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.loadByUniqueKey(AbstractEntityPersister.java:2159)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.loadByUniqueKey(EntityType.java:692)
>     at org.hibernate.type.EntityType.resolve(EntityType.java:434)   at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.doInitializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:151)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.engine.internal.TwoPhaseLoad.initializeEntity(TwoPhaseLoad.java:125)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.performTwoPhaseLoad(AbstractRowReader.java:238)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.AbstractRowReader.finishUp(AbstractRowReader.java:209)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.process.internal.ResultSetProcessorImpl.extractResults(ResultSetProcessorImpl.java:133)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:122)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:86)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:167)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4004)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:508)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:478)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:219)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:278)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:121)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:89)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1213)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$1900(SessionImpl.java:203)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2753)
>     at
>   org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2727)
>     at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.get(SessionImpl.java:1049)    at
>   com.SSH.Action.Main.getContact(Main.java:70)  at
>   com.SSH.Action.Main.main(Main.java:44)

Comment: So, retrieve the data BEFORE you commit, then.  That's just how databases work - once you've done a commit, you can't fetch any more data from your statement.

Comment: have checked your database that row for all tables are properly inserted.

Comment: When you use Session.get and you get a null pointer it means that it didn`t find the row in database.

Comment: I have checked my contact table. It has only one column 'contact_id'. There is no any column  for 'address_id' nor 'phone_id'. Is that any affect on this error? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks guys, I got it, I make mistake at hibernate one-to-one mapping between contact and address table. So my contact table has only one column 'contact_id' and mismatch with its model class 'Contact.class', that is why I got NullPointerException.